# Is there a way to specify to use tags versus version with the 'origen rc tag' command?

Tags: origen-sdk

We don't want our tags prefaced with a 'v' such as 'v1.0.1'.  We would rather use '1.0.1'.  Perhaps something like this?

```
origen rc tag --no_version
```

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

of-info, yes in concept , we need to add the capability to allow users to specify if they need to prepend "v" or not.

We have had this discussion before here https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/pull/243 and you implemented a solution that was merged. A similar update would be required for Origen, so if you want to implement that, we can review!

Thanks!!